changing the HTML of the parent iframe with parent.document.write()
I can replace the entire HTML of a page by doing this:
document.open();
document.write("whatever");
document.close();

However, when I try to replace the entire HTML of the parent from an iframe it doesn't work:
parent.document.open();
parent.document.write("whatever");
parent.document.close();

I don't get any errors in the JS console - the parent page goes blank but whatever doesn't appear in it. I also tried it with top.document.open(), etc, and that yielded the exact same behavior.
Any ideas?

parent.document.open(); makes the page blank, wiping all the markup off, including the iframe and the running script in it. document.write is not the way to create documents, if you want to load a new document, load it from your server using location.href.

Modifying the parent document from an iframe using JavaScript, such as with parent.document.write(), can be tricky and is subject to several restrictions.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

because your context gets destroyed at the time you call the document.open method.
